# How to know how much memory redux store is taking?

Tags: redux

I am checking the performance of my angular project and I was checking the memory usage for this using memory of developer tools. As I am using Redux store it's showing memory utilized by angular project + redux store. How can I know how much memory redux store is taking?

Answer (score 2):

Since your Redux store is just a single variable, you can just

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(store.getState()).length)
```

to get a rough estimation in bytes.

Comment: sorry I am new to ngrx. I am using ngrx/data how can I get store here. When I am using console.log(JSON.stringify(store.getState()).length) I am getting error at store.

Comment: At some point you are creating a Redux store. Import it wherever you want to call this.

Comment: I did not create store I only created an entity PartEntityService that is extending EntityCollectionServiceBase class. Also when I am trying to access the store of this PartEntityService and then call getState() it says Property 'getState' does not exist on type 'Store<EntityCache>'Using this.partEntityService.store.getState() in my component like I am accessing this.partEntityService.entities$

Comment: Honestly, this does not really seem to be related to the `redux` library at all, I don't even know if they use that internally.
I think you can somehow use `select` to extract something for your state and this probably also do `select(state => state)` to get the full store contents, but at this point I am just guessing.

Comment: Yes its using all the ngrx libraries internally in ngrx/data. Unfortunately select is not working :(. Thanks for your help!